# How can I remove a list from another list using a field value of the element's type if i can't modify the class directly?

Tags: c#, list

Suppose I have a `List<Product>` named `big` of some object `Product` which has 2 fields, `ID` and `Name`. The list is fully populated, meaning that each element has both fields not `null`, although they can be.

I have another `List<Product>`, smaller than the first, named `small`, but this time the field `Name` is `null` for some elements, while `ID` is always present.

I want to remove `small` from `big` where `ID` is the same.

Example:

```
List<Product> big = { {1,A},{2,B},{3,C},{4,D} };
List<Product> small = { {1,null},{3,C} };
List<Product> result = { {2,B},{4,D}};
```

I can't modify the `Product` object, i.e. I can't implement `IEquatable<Product>`, and such interface isn't implemented, meaning that `big.Except(small)` or `big.RemoveAll(small)` or `big.Contains(anElementOfSmall)` won't work (for the sake of the question, I've tried them).

I want to avoid the double loop with iterator removal or similar, I'm searching for built-in functions with specific predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your Product that compares two `Product` based on `ID`. Then just use `Except` and pass the comparer:

```
var result = big.Except(small, new ProductComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Problem is I can't modify the `Product` class :(

Comment: you don't need to modify Product class. create a new class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Product>`

Comment: Oh, you're right! How come it didn't came to my mind?

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple predicate you can easily achieve it:

```
big.Where(p => !small.Any(o => o.id == p.id)).ToList();
```

which translates in: select from `big` where the element (`p`) doesn't suffice the case where an element `o` in `small` has the same `ID`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `Except` how to compare instances of `Product`.

```
public class ProductEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        //they're both the same instance or they're both null
        if(ReferanceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        //only one of them is null
        if(x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product prod)
    {
        return prod == null? 0 : prod.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}


big.Except(small, new ProductEqualityComparer())
```